# block certain websites using C++

Tags: c++, web, hook, block

I am looking for a way to block certain websites using C++.
The agent is installed in the End-User, and if an unauthorized site is accessed, it must be redirected to an error page.

The hosts file is not used because the user can modify it arbitrarily.
Here is a list of possible searches.
(I prefer blocking through hooking rather than developing a network driver.)

- Windows Filtering Platform
- Send FIN packet to server using WinPCAP
- DNS Query control

Browsers target IE, Chrome, and Edge.

What are the pros and cons of the above list?
Or, Is there any possible way other than the above list?

Since there is not enough development time, there is not much learning time.
If you know the API, documentation, or code snippets you can refer to, please respond.

Thankds.

Comment: The user can also arbitrarily remove your blocking software. And if you're managing user's computers (i.e. they are domain members and the users aren't administrators), then the users won't be able to arbitrarily modify the hosts file anyway! I'd say that what you're trying to do will not work as you imply. You should be filtering between the user and the network, or you should be managing the users' machines so they don't have admin rights on them.